# XSL: Why is there no `<xsl:else>` tag defined

Tags: xml, xslt

For condition checking either we go for `<xsl:choose>` or `<xsl:if>`

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="expression">
    ... some output ...
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    ... some output ....
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

<xsl:if test="$admin=$value1">
    <control>true</control>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not($admin=$value1)">
    <control>false</control>
</xsl:if>
```

Why is there no `<xsl:else>` tag defined?

when I use `<xsl:if>`, If there was `<xsl:else>`, I need not repeat the `test="not($admin=$value1)` condition.
`<xsl:choose>` is good when you have mutiple cases to check. Of course the above  will simulate a typical '**if-else**', but why so much lines of code
to simulate a **if-else** condition

I wonder why there no **`<xsl:else>`** tag defined for XSL? Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Why not just use a `<xs:choose>` with a single `<xs:when>` and a single `<xs:otherwise>`?

Comment: If you're using XSLT idiomatically, you shouldn't have to worry about `xsl:if`s or `xsl:choose`s all that often.

Comment: I agree with both of your comments. But as i mentioned, I liked to know whythere is no else part for the if, compared to many other language syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing so requires the *parent node* to perform the condition logic in addition to logic with respect to the pairings - as both the `xsl:if` and `xsl:else` nodes would be *independent siblings*. This same "issue" exists in other tree-based control syntax structures, like Knockout.

While the `xsl:if` could hypothetically have supported the follow to avoid the previous issue (that of the nodes being siblings), doing so also makes it more difficult to use in the trivial case.

```
<xsl:if test="$admin=$value1">
    <xsl:then-hypothetical>
       <control>true</control>
    </xsl:then-hypothetical>
    <xsl:else-hypothetical>
       ..
    </xsl:else-hypothetical>
</xsl:if>
```

Furthermore, as JLRishe pointed out, this approach would be greatly inferior to `xsl:choose` which supports an arbitrary number of condition branches, in that each "else if" branch would introduce an additional level (or two) of nested elements.

So, when a true "else" is desired, just use `xsl:choose`.

Comment: Yes, exactly my thoughts: this structure just mirrors `<xsl:choose>-<xsl:when>-<xsl:otherwise>`.

Comment: It would actually be worse than `xsl:choose`, as each `else-if` would require deeper and deeper nesting.

Comment: @JLRishe A very good observation. I've added such to my answer.

Comment: Appreciate your responses and efforts

Answer (score 3):

Because `<xsl:else>` *element*, if it existed, would have to be attached to `<xsl:if>` - and that breaks one of the XML founding concepts: unless elements are grouped under a common parent, they are independent. In other words, the fact that in the following structure...

```
<xsl:if test="$admin=$value1">
    <control>true</control>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:else>
    <control>false</control>
</xsl:else>
```

... the latter follows the former is (or at least should be) meaningless: siblings are independent, and `test` attribute of `<xsl:if>` element in no case will be considered attached to `<xsl:else>`.

Now, you might say that one may put both `<xsl:if>` and the related `<xsl:else>` under the same parent. That's true, of course, - but the resulting structure could (thanks for @JLRishe for mentioning that) only be inferior to `<xsl:choose>-<xsl:when>-<xsl:otherwise>`, because eash `else-if` pair would require deeper nesting.

Comment: Thank you raina. I want to mark both as answers :) . Both of you explained very clearly. +1.

Comment: Sorry that i could not mark this as answer. But I appreciate your efforts in trying to make me understand. I marked the other as answer as it has more details.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `<xsl:else>` because the language's "if-then-else" is simply a subset of the `<xsl:choose>` implementation of "if-elseif-elseif-elseif-else".

Remember the XSLT was initially chapter 2 of the XSL-FO specification (in fact, it still is but by reference, not by inclusion).  When working with XSL-FO there are many cases where "if-then" is needed, not "if-then-else".  For example, consider adding a default property in a literal result element and then overriding it:

```
  <fo:block font-size="10pt">
    <xsl:if test="$needSmallFont">
      <xsl:attribute name="font-size">8pt</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:block>
```

Since "if-then-else" is already covered by `<xsl:choose>`, this requirement meant it was necessary to create an XSLT equivalent to "if-then" which is tighter than a choose with a single when.

This is the first appearance of `<xsl:if>` in a specification, and it answers the original question:

> http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/WD-xsl-19980818#AEN1090
>
> "The xsl:if instruction provides simple if-then conditionality; the
>   xsl:choose instruction supports selection of one choice when there are
>   several possibilities."

Comment: Thank you G.KenHolman . Your answer emphasized that an if else condition need to be handled using choose:when.. And not using if and ifnot as I checked in my code above.  Also there is one more reason other than independent siblings. And that is clear that you showed the specification. Thank you.  +1